# How do i use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parse in this table without id or class

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

Let's assume I have a table like this:

```
$html = str_get_html('<table class="mytab">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Situation</th>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <a href="#">John</a>
    </td>
    <td class="s">
    <strong>Yes</strong>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
    <a href="#">Allan</a>
    </td>
    <td class="s">
    <strong>No</strong>
    </td>
    </tr>
    ..
    </table>');
```

And let's assume I want to get ONLY the content from a person called 'John'  and only if that day his situation is 'Yes'.
I've tried some things and I was able to get all names from the table with `foreach($html->find('table.mytab tr') as $content) { $name = $content->first_child();` but I want to compare with an array of names `$people = array("John", "Dennis", "James");` and only if his situation is 'yes'.
can someone help me?

Comment: You should be able to use `if(strPos($content->children(1),'Yes') >= 0)` in your loop to check against the Yes/No value... but what do you want to do with the name once you've found one whos situation is 'Yes'?

Comment: I just want to use an 'echo' to show both name and his situation for now, later I will work on how to send values to my db..
As everytime I find that "John" situation is 'yes' I will insert into my db name, situation and date, if situation is 'no' that day it won't...
something like that

Comment: `$people = array('John', 'Greg', 'Mike');
$situation = array('Yes');

$table = $html->find('table', 0);
$rowData = array();

foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {
    $content = array();
    foreach($row->find('td') as $cell) {

        $content[] = $cell->plaintext;
    }
    $rowData[] = $content;
}

echo '<table>';
foreach ($rowData as $row => $tr) {
    echo '<tr>'; 
    foreach ($tr as $td)
    echo '<td>' . $td .'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    
}
echo '</table>';`

All right people I got to this point but I have no idea how to filter only 'John' with the condition 'Yes', help pls